# The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'

Tags: flutter, dart, double

I have a function that takes double as input and I'm passing a double value. I then get the error message:

**The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'**

```
for (var i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
  final double f = found[i];

  if (_aboveTreshold(f)) {
    ....
  }
}
```

And the method of signature is quite simple.

```
bool _aboveTreshold(double value) {

...
}
```

Is it really not possible to have a double as a parameter or am I doing something wrong?

This is an unexpected error message for me.

Why shouldn't 'double' be 'double'?

So as a workaround I made the function generic and then cast the value back to double. This is a dirty workaround. Is there a better way?

```
bool _aboveTreshold<T>(T value) {
  final v = value as double;

  ....
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's more code from the TFLite example to understand where 'found' comes from. It's 'List' that I get.

```
final interpreter = await _loadModel('assets/tf_lite_models/mobilenet_v1_1.0_128_1_default_1.tflite');
final imageMatrix = _buildImageMatrix(imageBytes, 128, 128);

final input = [imageMatrix];
final output = [List<double>.filled(1001, 0)];

interpreter.run(input, output);

var foundedLabels = _runClassification(output.first).keys.join(',');
```

the method:

```
 Map<String, double> _runClassification<double>(List<double> found) {
    final classification = <String, double>{};

    for (int i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {

      if (_aboveTreshold(found[i])) {
        classification[_labels[i]] = found[i];
      }
    }      

    return classification;
  }
}
```

In the development environment, the value is also displayed as List.

[image]

Comment: how u define you `found` what is inside the `found`?

Comment: List<double> is 'found'. it is a result of third party lib function (tflite interpreter).

Comment: are you sure it is a `List<double>` and not `List<double?>` ? The question mark is important

Comment: @Ivo I have expanded my post. yes i am sure, because the result from the interpreter is a 'List<double>'. I also saw the result list in the debugger. It says either 0.0 or the corresponding probability, such as 0.023400. For the ouput the interpreter even asked for a 'List<double>' in the 'run' function and not List<double?>. If I set 'output' to List<double?> and everything else to 'List<double?>' instead of 'List<double>' then the error comes instead:

The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double?'.dartargument_type_not_assignable

Comment: The code seems to work if you replace the signature
     `Map<String, double> _runClassification<double>(List<double> found) `
by
     `Map<String, double> _runClassification(List<double> found) `

Not sure what the  `<double>` there actually means.

Comment: Thanks for all the stimulating thoughts.

Comment: As samy stated, your problem is that `Map<String, double> _runClassification<double>(List<double> found)`  declares a generic function whose generic type parameter is *named* `double`.  That generic type parameter could be named anything, but you chose a name of an existing type.  That is, it's the same thing as `Map<String, T> _runClassification<T>(List<T> found)`.

Answer (score 1):

I now have a solution which is pretty weird, but it worked so I don't need a workaround anymore. If you have this weird problem too, I hope it helps.

The original if condition didn't work. I couldn't compare two doubles. Then I outsourced the if condition to a function and the error described above came up. As a workaround I made this function generic.

But after a bit of tweaking back and forth, I was able to fix all the bugs.

First, I removed the '_aboveTreshold' function. Now the original error came back that I can't compare found[i] with a double.

```
if (found[i] >= 0.9)
```

To fix that, I did the generic methods trick again. I turned _runClassification into a generic method.

```
 Map<String, T> _runClassification<T>(List<T> found) {
    final classification = <String, T>{};

    for (int i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {

      if ((found[i] as double) >= 0.900) {
        classification[_labels[i]] = found[i];
      }
    }      

    return classification;
  }
}
```

After that, the error messages were gone again in principle. Then save again and use the debugger.

In the end I also removed the second workaround and now it works without workarounds. It took a few tries.

```
  Map<String, double> _runClassification(List<double> found) {
    final classification = <String, double>{};

    for (int i = 0; i < found.length; i++) {
      if (found[i] >= 0.9) {
        classification[_labels[i]] = found[i];
      }
    }

    return classification;
  }
```

I hope this helps anyone who has this for no reason.